# Prove by induction that $x^{n}$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis

Prove by induction on n that for all $n\in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$ the function $p_{n}: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $p_{n}=x^{n}$ is continuous.

I know it can be done using Construction Theorem, but I don't know what it would look like using a limit/epsilon-delta proof with specifically induction.

Comment: I think you need to use the fact that the product of two continuous functions is again a  continuous function.

Comment: How would I then use induction with that? It must be applied to n.

Comment: The answer is already given below. Please take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

As hinted in the comments, you're likely supposed to use that the product of continuous functions is again continuous.

Now, let's prove that $p_n(x) = x^n$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ for all $n \geq 1$. Our base case is $n=1$, which you can show directly by an $\epsilon-\delta$ argument.

Next, we assume that $p_n(x)$ is continuous for all $1 \leq n \leq N$ and deduce that $p_{N+1}(x)$ is also continuous. To see this, note that
\begin{align*}
p_{N+1}(x) = x^{N+1} = x^N \cdot x = p_N(x)p_1(x)
\end{align*}
is the product of continuous functions (by our inductive hypothesis) and must therefore also be continuous.

Comment: Yes, thank you I see now how the construction and induction need to work together thank you.

Comment: @A.A. No problem, glad we could help.